# Trump's proclivity for withholding foreign or military aid?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy

Besides Ukraine, has the Trump Administration withheld or postponed aid (foreign or military aid) to another country?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a couple instances where aid was actually withheld for a period of time (there may be other cases that I have not found).

[NPR (Aug 2018): U.S. Cuts More Than $200 Million In Aid To Palestinians](https://www.npr.org/2018/08/24/641689522/u-s-cuts-more-than-200-million-in-aid-to-palestinians)

> The Trump administration announced Friday that it has cut nearly all the money the U.S. had planned to spend on aid projects for the Palestinians this year —including money to address a humanitarian crisis in the Gaza Strip.

[NPR (Jan 2017): Trump Bans U.S. Funding For Groups That 'Promote' Abortion Overseas](https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2017/01/23/511246176/trump-bans-u-s-funding-for-groups-that-promote-abortion-overseas)

> On Monday, the new president signed a presidential memorandum reinstating the "Mexico City" policy — barring U.S. aid from any group that provides or "promotes" abortion overseas.

There were also some cases where Trump had proposed or threatened cuts to foreign aid, but those cases never materialized.

[Time (Oct 2018): President Trump Threatens to Cut Off Foreign Aid Over Migrant Caravan](https://time.com/5430841/trump-foreign-aid-migrant-caravan/)

> President Donald Trump said Monday he will move to cut foreign aid to Guatemala, Honduras and El Salvador for failing to stop people “coming illegally into the U.S.”

[Reuters (May 2017): Republicans push back against Trump plan to cut foreign aid](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-budget-foreign-aid/republicans-push-back-against-trump-plan-to-cut-foreign-aid-idUSKBN18J2DC)

> U.S. President Donald Trump’s fellow Republicans in Congress on Tuesday assailed his proposed cuts in the diplomatic and foreign aid budget, making it unlikely the cutbacks in global health, peacekeeping and other programs will take effect.

And finally, as for an implied question of, "Has Trump withheld aid in the past, if so, why is it a big deal now?" (Note that I'm not saying that you are asking this, just that it is a reasonable next question.) The issue at hand now with Ukraine is not merely that he has withheld foreign aid to Ukraine that had been allocated by Congress, but also that his rationale for doing so appears to be one, for his own personal benefit, and two, counter to the national interests of the United States.

Comment: Good answer, +1, but that's a fair amount of opinion, not established fact at the end of this answer.  I had forgotten about the caravan aid.  You may also want to add: https://www.wsj.com/articles/u-s-freezes-military-aid-to-lebanon-11572660852